How to find the transfer function of an inverting op-amp?
The images provided are taken from a homework and it is not subjected to copyrights rules
I was asked to find the Transfer Function of the following circuit:

The answer provided by the teacher was H(s)=-R2/R1 (inverting op-amp), but I couldn't understand why Ra was not taken into consideration, if Vout was the voltage across Ra then it would've been understandable.

There is no load, so there is no current through Ra, so drop over Ra is zero.

justme tells you exactly why \$R_a\$ doesn't matter. For the circuit, as shown, there is no current in \$R_a\$. So there is no voltage drop across it. So the output shown is the same as the opamp output and you can simply ignore \$R_a\$ for these purposes.
Ignoring \$R_a\$ (because you can here) find:
solve( [ Eq( x/r1 + x/r2, vin/r1 + vout/r2), Eq(x,0) ],[ x, vout ] )[vout]/vin
-r2/r1

And there it is.
